# How to merge lists into a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, merge, tuples

What is the Pythonic approach to achieve the following?

```
# Original lists:

list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list_b = [5, 6, 7, 8]

# List of tuples from 'list_a' and 'list_b':

list_c = [(1,5), (2,6), (3,7), (4,8)]
```

Each member of `list_c` is a tuple, whose first member is from `list_a` and the second is from `list_b`.

Answer (score 555, accepted):

In Python 2:

```
>>> list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list_b = [5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> zip(list_a, list_b)
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
```

In Python 3:

```
>>> list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list_b = [5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> list(zip(list_a, list_b))
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
```

Comment: you have to know that the zip function stops at the end of the shortest list, which may not be always what you want. the `itertools` module defines a `zip_longest()` method which stops at the end of the longest list, filling missing values with something you provide as a parameter.

Comment: @Adrien: cheers for your applicable comment. For Python 2.x, `s/zip_longest()/izip_longest()`. Renamed in Python 3.x to `zip_longest()`.

Comment: could I create [(1,5), (1,6), (1,7), (1,8), (2,5), (2,6) ,so on] using zip command?

Comment: @MonaJalal: no, that's not pairing up, that's creating the *product* of the lists. `itertools.product()` does that.

Comment: note, at least in python3.6 zip does not return a list. So you need list(zip(list_a,list_b)) instead

Answer (score 147):

In python 3.0 zip returns a zip object. You can get a list out of it by calling `list(zip(a, b))`.

Comment: This might be trivial, but be warned that using this directly in a for loop gives you a generator that will be exhausted after using it once. Save into a variable if you want to use it more often

Answer (score 16):

You can use map lambda

```
a = [2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7]
c = map(lambda x,y:(x,y),a,b)
```

This will also work if there lengths of original lists do not match

Comment: Why use a lambda? `map(None, a,b)`

Comment: I only have have access to python 3.5.

Comment: If you were using python3 then c would not be a list it would be a map object, also using a lambda is going to be a lot less efficient than just zipping, if you have different length lists and want to handle that then you would use izip_longest/zip_longest

Comment: it does not work when "lengths of original lists do not match".

Comment: In [56]: a = ("a","b","c","d","e")

In [57]: b = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

In [58]: s = list(map(lambda x,y:(x,y),a,b))

In [59]: print(s)
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 5)]
No issue for me with miss matched lengths

Comment: Hi @DarkKnight:  Thank you for the solution. lambda works for me. I am thinking of creating a function by passing multiple lists/arguments in the form of `*args`.   is there any dynamic way to zip multiple lists depending on different scenarios?

Answer (score 8):

Youre looking for the builtin function [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure if this a pythonic way or not but this seems simple if both lists have the same number of elements :

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

list_b = [5, 6, 7, 8]

list_c=[(list_a[i],list_b[i]) for i in range(0,len(list_a))]
```

Answer (score 6):

The output which you showed in problem statement is not the tuple but list

```
list_c = [(1,5), (2,6), (3,7), (4,8)]
```

check for

```
type(list_c)
```

considering you want the result as tuple out of list_a and list_b, do

```
tuple(zip(list_a,list_b))
```

Comment: From my point of view, it seem's what I'm looking for and to work fine for the both (list and tuple). Because when you use **print**, you will see the right value (as expected and mentionned by @cyborg and @Lodewijk) and nothing related to the **object** such as : `<map object at 0x000001F266DCE5C0>` or `<zip object at 0x000002629D204C88>`. At least, the solution about **map** and **zip** (alone) seem's to be incomplete (or too complicated) for me.

Comment: The question states they want a list of tuples not a tuple of tuples.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question and was already answered, but for some reason, I still wanna post this alternative solution. I know it's easy to just find out which built-in function does the "magic" you need, but it doesn't hurt to know you can do it by yourself.

```
>>> list_1 = ['Ace', 'King']
>>> list_2 = ['Spades', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds']
>>> deck = []
>>> for i in range(max((len(list_1),len(list_2)))):
        while True:
            try:
                card = (list_1[i],list_2[i])
            except IndexError:
                if len(list_1)>len(list_2):
                    list_2.append('')
                    card = (list_1[i],list_2[i])
                elif len(list_1)<len(list_2):
                    list_1.append('')
                    card = (list_1[i], list_2[i])
                continue
            deck.append(card)
            break
>>>
>>> #and the result should be:
>>> print deck
>>> [('Ace', 'Spades'), ('King', 'Clubs'), ('', 'Diamonds')]
```

Comment: Changing one of the input lists (if they differ in length) is not a nice side-effect. Also, the two assignments to `card` in the `if-elif` are not needed, that’s why you have the `continue`. (In fact, without the `continue` you wouldn’t have to change the lists: both earlier mentioned assignments should then be kept and become `card = (list_1[i], '')` and `card = ('', list_2[1])` respectively.)

Answer (score 2):

Or `map` with unpacking:

```
>>> list(map(lambda *x: x, list_a, list_b))
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative without using `zip`:

```
list_c = [(p1, p2) for idx1, p1 in enumerate(list_a) for idx2, p2 in enumerate(list_b) if idx1==idx2]
```

In case one wants to get not only tuples 1st with 1st, 2nd with 2nd... but all possible combinations of the 2 lists, that would be done with

```
list_d = [(p1, p2) for p1 in list_a for p2 in list_b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like me, if anyone needs to convert it to list of lists (2D lists) instead of list of tuples, then you could do the following:

```
list(map(list, list(zip(list_a, list_b))))
```

It should return a 2D List as follows:

```
[[1, 5], 
 [2, 6], 
 [3, 7], 
 [4, 8]]
```