# merging lists in python

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python - merge items of two lists into a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/python-merge-items-of-two-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples)

There are two lists

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

How can I get the list

```
z = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e')]
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/python-merge-items-of-two-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples

Answer (score 3):

```
z = zip(x,y)
```

will do your job.

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> y = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> z = zip(x,y)
>>> z
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your input, the builtin function `zip(x, y)` will provide the output, that you want.

see: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = ['a','b','c','d','e']
print zip(x,y)
```