# Python: how do I merge lists to create a nested list

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python - merge items of two lists into a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/python-merge-items-of-two-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples)

How do I merge two lists in a nested way?

Eg:

```
list1 = a,b,c

list2 = d,e,f
```

I want the output to be:

```
[[a,d][b,e][c,f]]
```

Answer (score 16):

Just `zip` them:

```
>>> l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
>>> zip(l1, l2)
[('a', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'f')]
```

If you need lists, not tuples, in the result:

```
>>> [list(l) for l in zip(l1, l2)]
[['a', 'd'], ['b', 'e'], ['c', 'f']]
```

Comment: if you are working with large lists/generators you can also use `itertools.izip`

Answer (score 5):

Direct copy and paste from book:

**The zip function**

Sometimes it’s useful to combine two or more iterables before looping over them.
The zip function will take the corresponding elements from one or more iterables
and combine them into tuples until it reaches the end of the shortest iterable:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> z = zip(x, y)
>>> list(z)
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```