# python: create list of tuples from lists

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have two lists:

```
x = ['1', '2', '3']
y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

and I need to create a list of tuples from these lists, as follows:

```
z = [('1','a'), ('2','b'), ('3','c')]
```

I tried doing it like this:

```
z = [ (a,b) for a in x for b in y ]
```

but resulted in:

```
[('1', '1'), ('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('2', '3'), ('3', '1'), ('3', '2'), ('3', '3')]
```

i.e. a list of tuples of every element in x with every element in y... what is the right approach to do what I wanted to do? thank you...

**EDIT:** The other two duplicates mentioned before the edit is my fault, indented it in another for-loop by mistake...

Comment: This question has already been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/python-merge-items-of-two-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples

Comment: Mea Culpa, couldn't find that in the search, thank you :)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use the builtin function [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip):

In Python 3:

```
z = list(zip(x,y))
```

In Python 2:

```
z = zip(x,y)
```

Answer (score 12):

You're looking for the [zip builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function.
From the docs:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zipped = zip(x, y)
>>> zipped
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Answer (score 10):

You're after the zip function.

Taken directly from the question: [How to merge lists into a list of tuples in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/python-merge-items-of-two-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples)

```
>>> list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list_b = [5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> zip(list_a,list_b)
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
```