# How do I create a list of tuple elements

Tags: python, list, tuples

Lets say I have three list:

```
List1 = [1,2,3]
List2 = [4,5,6]
List3 = [7,8,9]
```

And now I want to create a new list with tuple elements, but use the data from my previous lists:

```
NewList = [(1,4,7), (2,5,6), (3,6,9)]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - merge items of two lists into a list of tuples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/python-merge-items-of-two-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> List1 = [1,2,3]
>>> List2 = [4,5,6]
>>> List3 = [7,8,9]
>>> zip(*(List1, List2, List3))
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
>>>
```

Also, you will notice that the third element of the second tuple is different.  I think you have a typo in your question.

Comment: THANKS iCodez. also what do i set "zip(*(List1, List2, List3))", another list? because if i do that and i print it i get "<zip object at 0x024789B8>"

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer if performance is important for you , i suggest use [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) instead built-in `zip()` :

```
>>> l=[List1,List2,List3]
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> list(izip(*l))
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Comment: The OP said that he wants a list of tuples.  The `zip` function already does this.  Why import a function just to get the same result?  `itertools.izip` is only more efficient if you do not convert the result to a list.

Comment: @iCodez hmm, i think your right , as i saw the good performance of `izip` for myself i just wanted to gave a good suggestion but for this question its more efficient to use `zip` !

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to do it, just as an alternative.

```
>>> NewList = []
>>> i = 0
>>> while i <= len(List1)-1 :
        NewList.append(tuple(j[i] for j in (List1, List2, List3)))
        i+=1
>>>NewList
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```