# Cross merge list elements to get a list of tuples in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have already checked this post [How to merge lists into a list of tuples in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/python-merge-items-of-two-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples?newreg=1a73eac9e8aa4610aad450709f994774) but it doesn't seem to fit to my issue.

I want to merge multiple lists together to get a tuple for each multiplication.
So let's say:

```
listA = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
listB = [ 1 ,  2 ,  3 ,  4 , 5 ]
listC = ['!', '?', '=']
```

The lists do not have the same length.
My desired result would be:

```
result = [('a', 1, '!'), ('a', 1, '?'),  ('a', 1, '='),  ('a', 2, '!')...
```

As far as I got it, the zip() functions only joins two elements to a list together with the same index which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> listA = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> listB = [ 1 ,  2 ,  3 ,  4 , 5 ]
>>> listC = ['!', '?', '=']
>>> result = list(itertools.product(listA, listB, listC))
>>> result[:5]
[('a', 1, '!'), ('a', 1, '?'), ('a', 1, '='), ('a', 2, '!'), ('a', 2, '?')]
>>>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!