# insert item from an ordered list to a tuple according to index

Tags: python, nlp

```
mylist=[[('The','d'),('apple','n'),('is','v'),('red','a')],[('I','p'),('feel','v'),('fine','adv')]]
```

This is a list of lists of tuples, and I wish to create a new list of tuples with information from another list added to it accordingly.

```
new_list=[['b','i','o','o'],['o','o','o']]
```

for each sub_list of these two lists, I have the exact same number of items as illustrated, and I wish to add the first string of the first list in new_list to the first tuple of the first list in my_list, the second string of the first list in new_list to second tuple of first list in my_list, and so on.

The ideal output looks like this

```
output=[[('The','d','b'),('apple','n','i'),('is','v','o'),('red','a','o')],[('I','p','o'),('feel','v','o'),('fine','adv','o')]]
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions, thank you!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge lists into a list of tuples in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/how-to-merge-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Basically this question has been answered elsewhere, so I flagged the question as duplicate, but assuming that you are new to python, here is a solution to your problem.

```
output = [[(*t,c) for t,c in zip(l1,l2)] for l1,l2 in zip(mylist,new_list)]
```

The new `output` is created using a list nested list comprehension (creating a list of lists). To match corresponding items from two lists together, you can use `zip`, which returns a generator of `tuples` of these corresponding items. The `for` loop that iterates through these `tuples` unpacks them into two separate items, i.e.

```
for l1,l2 in zip(mylist,newlist)
```

groups the sublists of `mylist` and `newlist` together, which the `for` are then unpacked into the lists `l1` and `l2` during the `for` iteration. Finally, as the items of the sublists of `my_list` are `tuples`, I unpack these `tuples` 'on the fly' while generating the new tuple: `(*t,c)` is the same as `(t[0],t[1],c)`.
Please ask if anything stayed unclear.

Hope this helps.