# Faster way to take two lists of integers and create pairs of type list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, performance, loops

Questions have already been asked on how to make pairs of two lists, but all of them create the pair lists as [tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/how-to-merge-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples).

Let's say I have two lists, `list1` and `list2`

```
list1 = [0,2,4,6,8]
list2 = [1,3,5,7,9]
```

Merging both into one list of tuples:

```
pairs = list(zip(list1, list2))
print(pairs)
```

Output:

```
>>> [(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7), (8, 9)]
```

To change type of lists from tuple to list:

```
listPairs = [list(pair) for pair in pairs]
print(listPairs)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

Combining both:

```
combined = [list(i) for i in list(zip(list1, list2))]
```

Now my question is this: is there a faster pythonic way of doing this? List comprehension is already pythonic and relatively fast on relatively non-large lists, but is there a faster way? Or would this be the fastest way?

My concern is when I use this way on two lists where each is 300k+ in size.

Comment: Why don't you profile the approaches?

Comment: Depending on your specific use-case, a lazy mapping may be appropriate.

Comment: @DanielMesejo does profile mean provide a specific example? A scenario?

Comment: I meant why don't you measure the speed of the approaches you mentioned. Ultimately you are the one that will know what is best, after you measure the efficiency of the approaches.

Comment: @DanielMesejo Good point, but if I knew how to do that I would not have asked. I'm interested in the general case of applying this to large lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, a list comprehension is as efficient as you can get, provided you need all the results at one point in time. There is an edge case where `map` with a built-in function will be more efficient than a list comprehension. See [List comprehension vs map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map) for more details. So you can use:

```
pairs = list(map(list, zip(list1, list2)))
```

This should be marginally more efficient than:

```
pairs = [list(x) for x in zip(list1, list2)]
```

If you need performance beyond this marginal improvement, I suggest you utilise a specialist library such as NumPy: see [What are the advantages of NumPy over regular Python lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/what-are-the-advantages-of-numpy-over-regular-python-lists)

Comment: i create two list with 100 items  and tested this two solutions in the ipython with `%timeit` and get `12.1 µs` for map and `17.7 µs` for list do you think this is good?

Comment: @BearBrown, I know nothing of your use case. Whether or not it is acceptable depends on your needs. For such small lists, these marginally differences are probably irrelevant.