# Merging uneven Corresponding Elements from a method returning value in Dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy

How to sort the data that are stored in a global list after inserting them within a method; so that before they are stacked into another list in accordance to their inserted elements? Or is this a bad practice and complicate things in storing data inside of a global list instead of seperated ones within a method; and finally sorting them thereafter ?

Below is the example of the scenario

```
list= []
dictionary = {}

def MethodA(#returns title):
#searches for corresponding data using beautifulsoup
#adds data into dictionary
# list.append(dictionary)
# returns list


def MethodB(#returns description):
#searches for corresponding data using beautifulsoup
#adds data into dictionary
# list.append(dictionary)
# returns list
```

Example of Wanted output

```
MethodA():[title] #scraps(text.title) data from the web
MethodB():[description] #scraps(text.description) from the web
#print(list)
>>>list=[{title,description},{title.description},{title,description},{title.description}]
```

Actual output

```
MethodA():[title] #scraps(text.title) data from the web
MethodB():[description] #scraps(text.description) from the web
#print(list)
>>>list =[{title},{title},{description},{description}]
```

There are a few examples I've seen; such as using Numpy and sorting them in an Array;-

```
arraylist = np.array(list)
arraylist[:, 0]
#but i get a 'too many indices for array'- 
#because I have too much data loading in; including that some of them 
#do not have data and are replaced as `None`; so there's an imbalance of indexes.
```

Im trying to keep it as modulated as possible. I've tried using the norm of iteration;

but it's sort of complicated because I have to indent more loops in it;

I've tried Numpy and Enumerate, but I'm not able to understand how to go about with it. But because it's an unbalanced list; meaning that some value are returned as `None`gives me the return error that; `all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly`

Example : `({'Toy Box','Has a toy inside'},{'Phone', None }, {'Crayons','Used for colouring'})`

> Update; code sample of methodA

```
def MethodA(tableName, rowName, selectedLink):
    try:
        for table_tag in selectedLink.find_all(tableName, {'class': rowName}):
            topic_title = table_tag.find('a', href=True)
            if topic_title:
                def_dict1 = {
                    'Titles': topic_title.text.replace("\n", "")}
                global_list.append(def_dict1 )
        return def_dict1 
    except:
        def_dict1 = None
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge lists into a list of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/how-to-merge-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: Can you post an example of data and your required output?

Comment: @Thomas Kuhn; it's not a duplicate as I've tried following your provided reference before posting this. Problem was; in the example; it's storing data into two arrays and merging them into one new array. My scenario is; I have two methods; returning values and storing them into one global list; I've tried Zip; Numpy; enumarate, in order to sort data. But I'm having an obstacle; because all the examples show how it's done with two seperate arrays; hence mine is trying to sort the data within the method; so they're saved into one global list. I'll update my question to provide.

Comment: @Mstaino question has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have something of the form:

```
x = [{'a'}, {'a1'}, {'b'}, {'b1'}, {'c'}, {None}]
```

you can do:

```
dictionary = {list(k)[0]: list(v)[0] for k, v in zip(x[::2], x[1::2])}
```

or

```
dictionary = {s.pop(): v.pop() for k, v in zip(x[::2], x[1::2])}
```

The second method will clear your sets in `x`

Comment: do I create new dicts; ?
`s= {}`
`v={}`

and pop it?

for some reason i'm receiving empty value whenever I try to print the dictionary. I'll upload the code to provide a better understanding how the value is retrieved and stored.

Comment: Just to clarify: `{'a1'}` is a `set`, not a dictionary. If you have a one element set, you can pass it to a value using `pop(s)` or `list(s)[0]`. I understood that from your original code. As for your question, you are using `return def_dict1` only if your `try` succedes, and `def_dict1`gets defined only when `if topic title` succedes. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Bottom line is: once you have all the data in a sorted manner (even if it is not the manner you want), it is generally easy to re-structure it the way you want. This is way we keep asking for a sample of your actual format vs. your expected format

Comment: To answer your first question; yes, only if the `ref` is `True` then will it proceed to extract data and proceeds to define that set inside the dict. Hence; it gets all the data from every href link and sets it into the dict. From thereon; it should get appended into the list but I also want to print all the sets in its current dict whenever I call the function. So, with every data appended into the list outside of the method, I'm trying to sort the data that has been appended to go as from

Comment: so the expected output becomes 
`MathodA = {'DetailA':'data','DetailA':'data}`
`MethodB = {'DetailB':'data','DetailB':'data}`
to 
`Final = [{'DetailA':'data','DetailB':'data}{'DetailA':'data','DetailB':'data}]`

Comment: Then you should probably use the first option, working with one set elements is messy, and generally pointless. You cannot sort them, and numpy interprets them as objects, unlike lists or tuples (which simply add to the array dimension). Pass the sets to a list or to an element instead.