# How to merge a list and a multi dimensional list while keeping a certain order

Tags: python, list

I have 1 list of names:

```
[VendorName1, VendorName2, VendorName3, VendorName4]
```

and I have a multidimensional list of emails varying in sizes:

```
[[email1@mail.com],[email2@mail.com,email3@mail.com],[email4@mail.com],[email5@mail.com,email6@mail.com,email7@mail.com]
```

This is what I have tried so far but I keep getting errors.

```
final=[]
  count=1
  for sub1 in vendor_names:
    for sub2 in vendor_emails:
      vendor_names[count].append(final)
      vendor_emails[count].append(final[1])
  print(final)
```

I would like to combine the 2 lists so that the final list is like:

```
[[[Vendor1,[email1@mail.com],[Vendor2,[email2@mail.com,email3@mail.com]]...]
```

Comment: Ok, and what was your attempt? You don't actually have `Vendor1` in your other list, you have `VendorName1` so it seems like a half-hearted request rather than something we can achieve. Should we be splitting the vendor name?

Comment: @roganjosh yeah let me edit my question real quick

Comment: I think you just want [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: @MarkMeyer zip() looks interesting let me give it a try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge lists into a list of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/how-to-merge-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip will do this just fine:

```
l1 = ['VendorName1', 'VendorName2', 'VendorName3', 'VendorName4']
l2 = [['email1@mail.com'],['email2@mail.com','email3@mail.com'],['email4@mail.com'],['email5@mail.com,email6@mail.com','email7@mail.com']]

print(list(zip(l1, l2)))
```

**Output:**

```
[('VendorName1', ['email1@mail.com']), ('VendorName2', ['email2@mail.com', 'email3@mail.com']), ('VendorName3', ['email4@mail.com']), ('VendorName4', ['email5@mail.com,email6@mail.com', 'email7@mail.com'])]
```

If you really don't want `tuples` (since they are immutable) you can do list comprehension but this requires that you don't have more vendors than emails:

```
l1 = ['VendorName1', 'VendorName2', 'VendorName3', 'VendorName4']
l2 = [['email1@mail.com'],['email2@mail.com','email3@mail.com'],['email4@mail.com'],['email5@mail.com,email6@mail.com','email7@mail.com']]

l3 = [[l1[x]] + [l2[x]] for x in range(len(l1))]
print(l3)
```

**Output:**

```
[['VendorName1', ['email1@mail.com']], ['VendorName2', ['email2@mail.com', 'email3@mail.com']], ['VendorName3', ['email4@mail.com']], ['VendorName4', ['email5@mail.com,email6@mail.com', 'email7@mail.com']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip(), but it merges lists to list of *tuples*.

**OR**

For merging lists to list of *lists*:

```
x = ['VendorName1', 'VendorName2', 'VendorName3', 'VendorName4']
y = [['email1@mail.com'], ['email2@mail.com', 'email3@mail.com'], [
    'email4@mail.com'], ['email5@mail.com', 'email6@mail.com', 'email7@mail.com']]
z = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    z.append([])
    z[i].append(x[i])
    z[i].append(y[i])
print(z)
```

**Output:**

```
[['VendorName1', ['email1@mail.com']], ['VendorName2', ['email2@mail.com', 'email3@mail.com']], ['VendorName3', ['email4@mail.com']], ['VendorName4', ['email5@mail.com', 'email6@mail.com', 'email7@mail.com']]]
```