# Making a list of [x, y] points from separate lists of [X] and [Y]

Tags: python, list, tuples, enumeration

I have two lists:

```
x_points = [0, 50, 100]
y_points = [10, 20, 30]
```

And I want to end up with a tuple of lists of the individual points, [x_i, y_i], like this: ([0, 10],[50, 20],[100, 30])

Is there an easier or more pythonic way than this enumeration?

```
result = tuple([x, y_points[i]] for i, x in enumerate(x_points))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip`.

```
x_points = [0, 50, 100]
y_points = [10, 20, 30]

print(tuple([x, y] for x, y in zip(x_points, y_points)))
# ([0, 10], [50, 20], [100, 30])
```

Or:

```
tuple(map(list, zip(x_points, y_points)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is extracted from the answer in the following post: [How to merge lists into a list of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/how-to-merge-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples)

```
>>> list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list_b = [5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> list(zip(list_a, list_b))
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even do

```
result=[(x_points[i],y_points[i]) for i in range(len(x_points))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x_points = [0, 50, 100]
y_points = [10, 20, 30]
result = tuple(map(list,zip(x_points, y_points)))

print(result)
```

output

```
([0, 10], [50, 20], [100, 30])
```