# How to get a list out of two lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists (both are already ordered correctly and contain 180.000 items each). The first one contains the filenames.

```
filenames[0]
s01_l01/1000_1.png
```

The second list contains the labels of the files.

```
labels[0]
'1BK 7475'
```

How do I now get a list, which looks like this: [[filename_1, label_1], [filename_2, label_2],..., [filename_n, label_n]]?

```
list_of_filenames_labels[0]
[s01_l01/1000_1.png, '1BK 7475']
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge lists into a list of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/how-to-merge-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a simple map with lambda function

```
a = ['1','2','3']
b = ['a','b','c']
c = list(map(lambda x, y: [x,y], a, b))
```

The output for c would be

```
c = [['1', 'a'], ['2', 'b'], ['3', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The output you specified is similar to the output of `zip`, except that it is a list of lists rather than a list of tuples.  This would convert them to lists:

```
[list(t) for t in zip(filenames, labels)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
list_of_filenames_labels = [[filename,label] for filename,label in zip(filenames,labels)]
```

Answer (score -1):

if both list have same length, you can use  `enumerate` function

```
list_of_filenames_labels = [[filename, labels[i]] for i, filename in enumerate(filenames)]
```