# (Python) How to Copy and Paste a column to another table?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 tables, is it possible I could merge 2 tables without merging by ID? Because the ID of these 2 tables are not consistent. These 2 Tables have the same amount of row. Great thanks if anyone could help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge lists into a list of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/how-to-merge-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: Besides the solutions in Karl's comment you might want to take a look at enumerate:
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#enumerate
It provides a way to create a temporary id for an  iterable.

Comment: I have tried both ways but seems not working and cannot Print the new value.
Is it possible you could help list the code.
Great Appreciate for your help!
@KarlWilhelm

Comment: You're going to have to show a lot more code if you expect to get a high quality answer. You should try to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it answers your question but try this code:

```
import pandas as pd

table1 = pd.DataFrame(table1) #Table with the first three columns
table2= pd.Series(table2) #Table with Price Prediction
table1["Price Prediction"] = table2
```

Comment: `table1 = pd.DataFrame(table1) #Table with the first three columns
table2= pd.Series(Prediction_df) #Table with Price Prediction
table1["Price Prediction"] = table2` 

However, it pop up 
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Do you know how it can be fixed?

Comment: It should work .. You may have a problem with column names or column types. Can you give additional information ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are better ways to achieve. However, I solve the problem by this

```
df_out = Table1.reset_index()

Prediction_df = pd.DataFrame(predictions)
Prediction_df = Prediction_df.rename(columns={'XXX': 'Prediction'})
Prediction_df['prediction'] = Prediction_df.reset_index()['Prediction']
df_out1 = pd.merge(df_out,Prediction_df[['prediction']],how = 'left',left_index = True, right_index = True)
```