# Alternating between functions in Python?

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to write a program that displays the lyrics for "Old MacDonald", but when I run the program, I'm getting all of my first function's repeats followed by my second function's repeats. What I'm saying probably doesn't make much sense. Just look at the code.

```
def verseFor(animal):
    lyrics = "Old MacDonald had a farm, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!\n" + \
    "And on that farm he had a " + animal + ", Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!"
    return lyrics

def verseFor2(noise):
    lyrics2 = "With a " + noise + ", " + noise + " here and a " + noise + ", " + noise + " there. Here a " + noise + ", there a " + noise + ", everywhere a " + noise + ", " + noise + ".\n" + \
    "Old MacDonald had a farm, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!"
    return lyrics2

def main():
    for animal in ["cow", "duck", "sheep", "horse", "dog"]:
        print(verseFor(animal))

    for noise in ["moo", "quack", "baa", "neigh", "woof"]:
        print(verseFor2(noise))

main()
```

Comment: Make it one function, [combine the lists into tuples, as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/how-to-merge-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples), and call the function on a tuple.

Comment: For future reference, a for loop is, well, a loop, and loops through itself before continuing on.

Comment: You got a good answer from @ThierryLathuille. I'd like to suggest one improvement. Your code calls for an f-string: `lyrics2 = f"With a {noise}, {noise} here and a {noise}, {noise} there. Here a {noise}, there a {noise}, everywhere a {noise}, {noise}.\nOld MacDonald had a farm, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good use for [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
def verseFor(animal):
    lyrics = "Old MacDonald had a farm, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!\n" + \
    "And on that farm he had a " + animal + ", Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!"
    return lyrics

def verseFor2(noise):
    lyrics2 = "With a " + noise + ", " + noise + " here and a " + noise + ", " + noise + " there. Here a " + noise + ", there a " + noise + ", everywhere a " + noise + ", " + noise + ".\n" + \
    "Old MacDonald had a farm, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!"
    return lyrics2

def main():
    for animal, noise in zip(["cow", "duck", "sheep", "horse", "dog"],
                             ["moo", "quack", "baa", "neigh", "woof"]):
        print(verseFor(animal))
        print(verseFor2(noise))

main()
```