# Insert elements from two different arrays into new one corresponding to its columns

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I am having two arrays:

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and

```
Y = [10,20,30,40,50]
```

I am trying to combine two arrays into one where items from array **X** correspond to *row=0* and items from array **Y** correspond to *row=1*.

So the new array looks like:

```
combined = [[1,10],[2,20],[3,30],[4,40],[5,50]]
```

I have tried the following methods:

```
for element in combined:
    for item in X:
        element[0] = item
```

This should add all elements from *X* into the first-row of *combined*
Like that:

```
combined = [[1, 0],[2, 0],[3, 0],[4, 0],[5, 0]]
```

However, it does not work like I expected as it gives me the following result:

```
combined = [[1, 0],[1, 0],[1, 0],[1, 0],[1, 0]]
```

Comment: try `list(zip(X,Y)) `

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge lists into a list of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/how-to-merge-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: @Pygirl, It does partially the work. It returns [(1,10), (2,10)] instead of [[1,10], [2,10]]. So it returns the objects

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) You set the first index of `element` to _every element of `X`_. At the end of the inner for loop, the first index is set to the last element of `X`. This happens for all `element` in `combined`. You only need to set the corresponding element of `X` to the first index of `element`

Comment: Then map them to a list by this :`list(map(list, zip(X, Y)))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use zip to make that kind of combination:

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5]
Y = [10,20,30,40,50]

Z = [ list(p) for p in zip(X,Y) ]

print(Z) # [[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 30], [4, 40], [5, 50]]
```