# How to show two list items result into one, for multiple results. Using python in selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This prints separately, how am I gone make it print consecutively, like the link and then the identifier

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr//td//a[@href]")
identifiers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr//td//code[@property='x']")

for elem in elems:
    href = elem.get_attribute("href")
    print(href)
for identifier in identifiers:
    print(identifier.text)
```

Comment: Use `zip` feature combining lists

Comment: I'm not really familiar with python can you atleast send me a link or teach me how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/how-to-merge-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples

Answer (score 1):

Use zip as suggested by @bigbounty. I am adding the code here.

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr//td//a[@href]")
identifiers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr//td//code[@property='x']")

for elem, identifier in zip(elems, identifiers):
     print(elem, identifier)
```